# How to store or handle the response from AndroidNetworking responce/OkHttp response

Tags: android

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Map<String,String> ipdetails = new HashMap<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getipDetails();
        Log.d("getipdetails", "showingdata after getip fun  execute is"+ ipdetails);
        //Trying to use AsyncTask for the same operation
        new AsyncNetworkoperation().execute();
    }

    private void getipDetails() {
        AndroidNetworking.get("https://freegeoip.live/json/")
                .build()
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            ipdetails.put("Country",response.getString("country_name"));
                            Log.d("getipdetails", "showingdata in getip fun  onResponce is"+ ipdetails);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {
                        ipdetails.put("Country","Error: "+anError.toString());
                    }
                });
    }
    private static final class AsyncNetworkoperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String country;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            AndroidNetworking.get("https://freegeoip.live/json/")
                    .build()
                    .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                country=  response.getString("country_name");
                                Log.d("getipdetails", "showingdata in getip fun in AsyncTask onResponce is "+country);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(ANError anError) {

                        }
                    });
            return country;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d("getipdetails", "showingdata in getip fun  onPostExecute is "+result);
        }
    }
}
```

above is my code in the android studio I'm trying to call getipDetails() and immediately I want to use the returned data.

but before executing getipDetails(), the returned value is executed and showing null.

I used AsyncTask but I failed.

so help me to implement my logic.

like after calling getipDetails() immediately I want to use the return value. I don't have restrictions in a data type that it returns. but I want it to be used after the function call.

---

below is my log, which is not executed as mentioned in the code.

1. D/getipdetails: showingdata after getip fun  execute is{}
2. D/getipdetails: showingdata in getip fun  onPostExecute is null
3. D/getipdetails: showingdata in getip fun  onResponce
   is{Country=India}
4. D/getipdetails: showingdata in getip fun in AsyncTask onResponce is
   India

---

Below is an image that has a log.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask and all other networking libraries work on background thread in parallel along with the main UI thread. Therefore when the method getipDetails() is called, it starts a new thread and the remaining code is executed along with the getipDetails(), hence the log is giving null output. You have return the response from the doInBackground() and accept in onPostExecute().

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Map<String, String> ipdetails1 = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> ipdetails2 = new HashMap<>();
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        execute();
        execute2();
    }

    public void execute() {

        Log.i("IP RES", "EXECUTING");
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://freegeoip.live/json/", null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        String country=null;
                        Log.i("Response from volley",response.toString());
                        try {
                            country=response.getString("country_name");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ipdetails1.put("country",country);
                        Log.i("IP Country from volley", ipdetails1.get("country"));

                        //Do whatever you want here

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                Log.i("Network Error",error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(req);

    }

    public void execute2(){
        AndroidNetworking.get("https://freegeoip.live/json/")
                .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        String country=null;
                        Log.i("Res Networking",response.toString());
                        try {
                            country=response.getString("country_name");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ipdetails2.put("country",country);
                        Log.i("from Networking", ipdetails2.get("country"));

                        //Do whatever you want here
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                        // handle error
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I have given both example using volley and and AndroidNetworking library, please don't use emulator for testing.